# javascript or jquery: show multiple variables in one alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Alert command assumes this structure:

```
alert (variable)
```

How to show multiple variables in a single alert?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? For debugging you should consider using `console.log` instead, which accepts multiple arguments.

Comment: Wait. Old IE browsers do not support `console.log`, which results in Javascript error, and break the codes.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor - It was supported from IE8 (the JS error only occurred if the console was actually closed when the code ran). But you probably wouldn't include `console.log()` in actual deployed production code so the point is moot.

Comment: Agree with you that `console.log` should not be used in production environment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> *Alert command assumes this structure: `alert (variable)`*

No, `alert()` assumes this structure:

```
    alert(some expression)
```

...where "some expression" is pretty much any JavaScript expression - if the expression is not a string it will be converted (though in some cases, e.g., for some objects the result might not be very meaningful).

So:

```
alert(variable);
alert("string literal");
alert(variable1 + variable2 + variable3);
alert(variable1 + ", " + variable2);
alert(resultOfFunctionCall());
alert([1,2,3]);
alert(whatever() + "else" + you.can.think + "of");
```

Or even:

```
alert();   // displays "undefined"
```

Note that if you are trying to debug your code you are better off using [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console.log) than `alert()`. If you are trying to produce a dynamic message to show the user just concatenate variables as needed, e.g.:

```
alert("Hello there " + name + ". Welcome.");
```

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean this :

```
alert (variable1 + ', ' + variable2);
```

No jQuery is required in this case.

Comment: Quick and easy.  Many thanks for this one.  Can recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

The below is how to do it:

```
var a = "Hello";
var b = "World!";

alert(a + b);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
window.alert = function (native) {
    return function (str) {
        var argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < argsArray.length; i++) {
            msg = argsArray[i];
            if (typeof (msg) == 'object') msg = JSON.stringify(msg);
            s += msg;
            if (i < (argsArray.length - 1)) s += ',  ';
        }
        native(s);
    }
}(window.alert);
```

Try this:

> alert("This", "That", {"this":"that"});

Comment: probably dont want to do that